# Plsql date function delete data in table

Tags: plsqldeveloper, toad

Good morning

In one table. I have LOADDATETIME column name- DATE datatype.. And value will be in the "13/06/2022 18:46:23"

I need to delete rows in the table by using Loaddatetime column..

How can I delete. Could u pls tell anyone

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of unclear what you actually have. Title mentions "PL/SQL" which reads as "Oracle" (it is procedural extension to its SQL). Tags you used (PL/SQL Developer and TOAD) are just *tools* we use to access various databases - and it doesn't have to be Oracle. Code depends on **database** you use, not a **tool**.

Anyway, I'll presume you do use Oracle (and suggest you to fix tags and be more specific next time).

---

This ("13/06/2022 18:46:23") is just *representation* of that column's value; Oracle stores it in its internal format (irrelevant for this discussion).

If you want to delete rows regarding to `loaddatetime` column, then it should be part of the `where` clause.

There are various options; you never said what *exactly* you want to delete, so here are a few examples.

To delete rows with exactly that date value (use `to_date` function which will - according to provided format model - convert that string into a valid date datatype value):

```
delete from your_table 
where loaddatetime = to_date('13/06/2022 18:46:23', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

To delete rows between two dates (I'm using date literals in this case):

```
delete from your_table
where loaddatetime between date '2022-06-01' and date '2022-06-15';
```

And so forth; for a more precise suggestion, be more specific.